# How set filled material design style forTextFormField in flutter?

Tags: flutter, material-design, textformfield

There are two designs for Text Fields in `Material Design`: 1. filled 2. outlined. But for some reason in flutter there is only one design option, this is - outlined. How you can add a filled style for TextFormField. It looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `InputDecoration(filled: true)`

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(filled: true),
),
```